# MySQL Formatting YEARWEEK(date)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble formatting SQL output of YEARWEEK(date_created) function.

I would like to format it as: **week04, December** or something similar with human being able easily to process.

Here's data which is being returned as:

```
SELECT 
    DATE(date_created) as date_,
    YEARWEEK(date_created) as week_
...
```

Result Set:

> date_   ---------------------------------------- week_
>
> 2017-12-30    -------------------------------- 201752
>
> 2018-01-06    -------------------------------- 201753
>
> 2018-01-10    -------------------------------- 201801

Why is 2018-01-06 (January the 6th of 2018) considered as 53th week of 2017?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DATE_FORMAT`:

```
SELECT
    '2018-02-01' AS date_,
    CONCAT('week', DATE_FORMAT('2018-02-01', '%V, %M')) AS week_
FROM dual;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Amazing response. Just one little thing if you could help me how to provide (week MOD 4 + 1) so I can get week01-04 in current month?

Comment: @Lululu There is no straightforward way to get the week of the current month.  If you really require that, you might need to write a UDF or a stored procedure to compute it.  My answer stands the way it is, reporting the week of the year and the full month name.

Comment: Yes, your answer seems well correct, but I got issue representing '2017-12-30 11:00:00' as week 1 December. Don't know how it got 1 as week number?

Comment: Try using `%V` for the week instead of `%U`.  See the updated answer.

Comment: We're in circle I guess, now '2018-01-06 11:00:00' is represented as '53, January'.

Comment: No circles.  A year does not have an even number of weeks.  Sometimes it spans 52 or 53 weeks.  As I mentioned, what you are asking for is non trivial.

Comment: Thanks for response, this will do the job =) If nothing else, I could put one IF clause to check if week number is 53, January to convert it to 01, January.

Comment: But be careful: some years December will have a 53rd week.  Stare at a calendar and you will see where the confusion in the API comes from.

Comment: The 1st of February is not in the fourth week of February, but in the first.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen My bad, actually that statement week 53, January is correct as long as December and January have one common week. Again thanks a lot for response!

Comment: @ThorstenKettner With usage of modulo (week%4+1), I think we will get over it.

Comment: @Lululu: No. '2017-03-30' is the fifth week of March. It is also the 13th week in the year. But 13 % 4 + 1 = 2.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DATE_FORMAT`

```
    SELECT '2018-01-06' AS date_, CONCAT('Week',DATE_FORMAT('2018-01-06','%u, %M ')) FROM DUAL
```

Comment: The OP wants the full month name but your query does not provide that.

Answer (score 0):

`YEARWEEK` reports ISO weeks. But you want something like "the fourth week of December" instead. That's a mere integer division; days 1 to 7 are the first week, days 8 to 14 the second, etc.

```
select 
  year(date_created) as year,
  monthname(date_created) as month,
  day(date_created) DIV 7 + 1 as week
from mytable;
```

Comment: This won't give the week of the particular month.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: Oops, that must be `day(date_created) DIV 7` of course. Thanks. I've corrected my answer.